# SQL-Server 2005: The multi-part identifier ... could not be bound.

Tags: sql, sql-server

My error message:

> The multi-part identifier table2.ValidSince" could not be bound.

```
UPDATE table1
SET table1.ValidSince = table2.ValidSince
WHERE table1.ID = '5C954C6F-FFD7-454A-9E2B-000076523819'
```

How do I need to change the update to make it work?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to join on to `table2`

```
UPDATE t1
SET t1.ValidSince = t2.ValidSince
From Table1 t1
Join Table2 t2 on t1.PKCol = t2.PKCol
WHERE t1.ID = '5C954C6F-FFD7-454A-9E2B-000076523819'
```

Answer (score 2):

You haven't declared `table2` anywhere in your statement.  You need to include `table2` in order to be able to use it.

```
UPDATE t1 
   SET t1.ValidSince = t2.ValidSince 
  FROM Table1 t1 
  JOIN #Table2 t2 
    ON t1.PKCol = t2.PKCol 
 WHERE t1.ID = '5C954C6F-FFD7-454A-9E2B-000076523819'
```

Comment: sorry table2 is a temporary table