# sql update table set - The multi-part identifier could not be bound

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-update

I have 2 tables:

- **Table1** = names of gas stations (in pairs)
- **Table2** = has co-ordinate information (longitude and latitude amongst other things)

Example of **Table1**:

```
StationID1  StationID2  Name1   Name2   Lattitude1  Longitude1  Lattitude2  Longitude2  Distance
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
93353477    52452   FOO     BAR     NULL        NULL        NULL    NULL    NULL
93353527    52452   HENRY   BENNY   NULL        NULL        NULL    NULL    NULL
93353551    52452   GALE    SAM     NULL        NULL        NULL    NULL    NULL
```

Example of **Table2**:

```
IDInfo     Name  Lattitude    Longitude
-------------------------------------------
93353477   BAR   37.929654    -87.029622
```

I want to update this table with the coordinate information which resides in `tableA`. I tried to do the following as per [SQL Server 2005: The multi-part identifier … could not be bound](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4933888/sql-server-2005-the-multi-part-identifier-could-not-be-bound)

```
update table1
set t1.[Lattitude1] = t2.[Lattitude]
from table1 t1
left join table2 t2 
on (t1.StationID1 = t2.IDInfo)
```

I get the following error message:

> *Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>
>   The multi-part identifier "t1.Lattitude1" could not be bound.*

However, if I do the following it works which I can then store into another table.

```
SELECT t1.[StationID1]
      ,t1.[StationID2]
      ,t1.[Name1]
      ,t1.[Name2]
        ,t2.[Lattitude] AS [Lattitude1]
        ,t2.[Longitude] AS [Longitude1]
        ,t3.[Lattitude] AS [Lattitude2]
        ,t3.[Longitude] AS [Longitude2]
from table1 t1
left join table2 t2 
on (t1.StationID1 = t2.IDInfo)
left join table2 t3 
on (t1.StationID2 = t2.IDInfo)
```

I am very new to SQL and am having a difficult time understanding why some things work and others don't. Based on the link I posted above my initial query should have worked - no? Perhaps I'm not thinking straight as I have spent many hours trying this and I finally got help from a co-worker (she suggested the approach I mention above).

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I think you can modify your UPDATE statement to reference the table alias in the UPDATE line.

```
update t1
set t1.[Lattitude1] = t2.[Lattitude]
from table1 t1
left join table2 t2 
on (t1.StationID1 = t2.IDInfo)
```

Comment: Better not to use an alias or repeat table1 in the FROM clause at all: update table1 set Lattitude1 = table2.Lattitude from table2 where table2.IDInfo = table1.StationID1.  SQL Server's "UPDATE ... FROM" construction is non-standard and - especially when aliases are used - a bit mysterious. If a table or alias name in the FROM clause matches what comes after UPDATE, those tables are magically identified, but this can break if a remote query is involved (see the help for UPDATE .. FROM, and http://bit.ly/14EXoZP).

Comment: @cgatian, bobs - thank you very much for your help. Both of your solutions worked. I have noted the problem Steve Kass mentioned just in case. Thank you all.

Answer (score 1):

You need to change the inner table and give a different allias to the columns that are similar. This should work.

```
update table1
set [Lattitude1] = x.[lat]
from 
(
    SELECT IDInfo [id], Lattitude [lat] FROM 
    table2
) x
WHERE
StationID1 = x.[id]
```

In your particular case its not necessary to rename Lattitude to lat, but if you end up updating a table with itself and force yourself into giving the columns different names, it will save you headaches down the road.